# contour plot 3d fix the problem

Tags: plotting

```
ContourPlot3D[{Im[-1.141088662*I - (.2852721655*Sqrt[8]*Sqrt[2])/ Tan[(2*Sqrt[2]*(0.6510416668*I*Sqrt[8]*x + (.2260561342*I)*Sqrt[8]*t^.5 + 1))]]},
  {x, -10, 10}, {t, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: if you look at help it says `ContourPlot3D` has the form `ContourPlot3D[...,{},{},{}]` but your  command has the form `ContourPlot3D[...,{},{},{},{}]` so you have an extra `{}` there. There should be only 3 `{}` and not 4 `{}`

Answer (score 2):

Your function does not depend on $y$ and $z$:

```
ContourPlot[Im[-1.141088662*I - (.2852721655*Sqrt[8]*Sqrt[2])/
  Tan[(2*Sqrt[2]*(0.6510416668*I*Sqrt[8]*x + (.2260561342*I)*Sqrt[8]*Sqrt[t] + 1))]],
  {x, -10, 10}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: For a cleaner plot: `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Im[-1.141088662*I - (.2852721655*Sqrt[8]*Sqrt[2])/
       Tan[(2*Sqrt[
           2]*(0.6510416668*I*Sqrt[8]*x + (.2260561342*I)*Sqrt[8]*
             Sqrt[t] + 1))]] // Rationalize[#, 0] & // 
   Simplify], {x, -10, 10}, {t, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 150, WorkingPrecision -> 15]`